# Error type, when I open a shapefile

Tags: qgis, shapefile, error

I'm new on qgis, when I open a shapefile this error appear:

```
File "C:/PROGRA~1/QGIS2~1.18/apps/qgis/./python/plugins\processing\gui\GeometryPredicateSelectionPanel.py", line 81, in onRightLayerChange
                self.updatePredicates()
              File "C:/PROGRA~1/QGIS2~1.18/apps/qgis/./python/plugins\processing\gui\GeometryPredicateSelectionPanel.py", line 88, in updatePredicates
                unusablePredicates = self.unusablePredicates[leftType][rightType]
            KeyError: 3
```

What means?

Answer (score 3):

Looking at the code on my local install (I'm using QGIS 2.18.3/Ubuntu).

This error means that one (or both) of your layers has a Geometry type which is **not** one of the following types:-

- Point
- Polygon
- Line

This is the code that turns options on/off for things like Intersects  / Contains / Within, whenever you select a layer. It makes sure you can only choose options which will work for the types of both layers.

If one of your layers is Polygon3D, Polygon25D, etc. then it would throw that exception.

It's strange, the value it's complaining about (3) refers to standard polygons, so it might not be that.

Can you edit your question with the exact version of qgis? Also mention which operation you were trying to perform in Processing (e.g. join attributes by location)